# CSS height auto clips contents on small device

Tags: html, css, materialize

If height is set to auto, why is it that on big screens the whole content of my responsive div is shown, but on smaller device height is not adjusted go show all contents, that is content is clipped or cut, how do you fix this issue?

```
.mycontainer {
     height: auto;
}

<div class="mycontainer">
    lots of text in divs
</div>
```

The above will cut the text content on smaller device.

Comment: Have you tried adding overflow: visible; to it? It should be set to that by default, but your div may possibly be inheriting an overflow property set on it's parent div. Or maybe the parent div of mycontainer div has a fixed height? You need to post more code.

Comment: here is the link, note that the first banner parallax has an auto height but does not adjust height on small devices, http://materializecss.com/templates/parallax-template/preview.html and the complete code, http://materializecss.com/templates/parallax-template.zip

Comment: It's because you have no vertical-align properties associated with the div that contains the text.

Comment: @SemanticUI: The web page seems alright on small screens to me.. ?

Comment: try adding more content Nvj and you will see.

Comment: media queries will fix this by shrinking text and buttons on smaller screens, and vertical align will help to center the content as devices switch from vertical to horizontal.  If you worked up a jsfiddle I could help you with exact css needed for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic vertical-align issue.  I don't have your specific html or css...which would be helpful next time, but just by going on the template page you sent:  The display properties of the parallax-container and the text container need to be changed to `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;`  Then you can add `vertical-align:middle;` to your text container which will move your text vertically without cutting it off.  However, since the font is the same size on all screens, you might want to use media queries to compress it on smaller screens, making better visibility on smaller devices as well.